# perl : how to know where a string matches in list?

Tags: arrays, list, perl, match

I have a list similar to this one :

```
my @foo=qw(bar foo fou foobar);
```

And I want to get the arrays in which there is a match (eg : with foo). I'm now using this code :

```
my $i=0;
foreach (@foo)
{
    print "$i\n" if "$_" eq "foo";
    $i+=1;
}
```

Which returns :

```
1
```

This code works, but I'd like to know if there is a smarter way to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by using `grep`:

```
my @foo = qw(bar foo fou foobar);
my @indices = grep { $foo[$_] eq 'foo' } 0 .. $#foo;
# @indices = (1)
```

That will give you an array of all matching indices.

Comment: Thank you, it was exactly what I wanted

Comment: There is no reason to continue searching after the first match is found.

Comment: @Borodin Why not? OP's original code finds all matching indices, so that's what my answer does.

Comment: @melpomene: I'm sorry. Somehow I read the question as wanting the index of the *first* matching element.

Comment: In my case, all elements have a different name, so there is not difference :)

Comment: @LéoPourcelot: In that case you probably want a *hash* instead of or in addition to the array. `my %indexes = map { $foo[$_] => $_ } 0 .. $#foo` and then `my $i = $indexes{'foo'}`. You need create the hash only once.

Comment: I just googled about _hashes_ (I didn't know what it is) and thank you for your answer, they are very usefull in this case.

Answer (score 2):

Use `first_index` from `List::MoreUtils`, like this

```
my $i = first_index { $_ eq 'foo' } @foo;
```

`$i` will be set to -1 if the value is not found.

This can easily be achieved in Perl, but `List::MoreUtils` is an XS module and so should run a little faster.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however, I think I will use melpomene's answer because it is written in pure-perl language.

Comment: @LéoPourcelot: I don't understand why you would avoid using an XS module. Once it is installed there is no way to tell the difference except that it's faster! If you insist on a pure Perl solution, then setting the environment variable `LIST_MOREUTILS_PP` will make the same module use Perl code instead of XS. You can do that from within the Perl program.

Comment: "Once it is installed"  ...which for many users is a hassle. I think seasoned perl programmers often forget that.

Comment: @KjetilS. One doesn't have to be *"seasoned"* to type `cpan List::MoreUtils`

Comment: @Borodin. I agree, but you need root/sudo access which many might not have on the systems they want to run their program on. Of course perlbrew and such can circumvent that in many cases, but newbees might not know those tools.

Comment: @KjetilS. You shouldn't be messing with the system perl on a shared computer anyway, but it's easy enough to install your own copy. But it's also easy to install your own modules in your user tree and keep using the system perl. All of this is documented, and I don't see that it's any different from other languages. Python, for instance, does the same thing through *virtual environments*, but I don't read about people who are reluctant to install Python packages. Where do you think the problem lies?

Comment: @Borodin: All perl programmers should of course learn how to install modules. It should however not necessarily be among the first things they learn. In my experience newbees are easily scared away from Perl when having to deal with module installation too early. Perl has a scary enough reputation already. Undeserved I think, but still.